# what data will be stored in stack in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

As my understanding all the class variable's  like instance members , static  members , constant s... their references will be saved in heap, and actual value of these variables will be saved in stack.

if it is only value type not refer by any reference type it will be stored in stack only like enum, apart from enum which data will be stored in stack memory.

if my understanding is wrong correct me.

Answer (score 1):

While reference types are always allocated on the heap, value types may be allocated on the stack - but not necessarily. A value type is only allocated on the stack when it is an unboxed non-escaping local or temporary variable that is not contained within a reference type and not allocated in a register.

What will NOT en up in the stack:

- a value type as part of a class will end up on the heap.
- if boxed, it will end up on the heap.
- if an array, it will end up on the heap.
- if it's a static variable, it will end up on the heap.
- if captured by a closure, it will end up on the heap.
- If used in an iterator or async block, it will end up on the heap.
- If created by unsafe or unmanaged code, it could be allocated in any type of data structure (not necessarily a stack or a heap).

Enums will only be "allocated" in the stack when they're not allocated as part of some other structure, like an array.