# What is major importance/role of stack memory if most of the data go on heap?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I was reading about Dispose pattern and come across how the [memory is allocated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/). Following is the quote from http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2008/04/28/foundations-of-programming-pt-7-back-to-basics-memory/.

> **Memory Allocation**
>   ....
>   ....
>   The only exception to this rule are value types belonging to reference types – for example the Id property of a User class goes on the heap along with the instance of the User class itself.

This is also mentioned on question on Stack Overflow here.  [memory allocation for value type inside reference type in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11876503/5779732)

My understanding was that, all value types irrespective of where they are declared go to stack. This looks wrong now. In the code below, `i` will go on heap; NOT on stack according to the links. This is because `MyClass` is reference type which will go to heap and along with it, all its value types.

```
class MyClass()
{
    int i = 5;
}
```

Ok, so only value types those are not a part of class go to stack memory then. Right? But, almost everything in Dot Net language like C# is inside class. Then what exactly go to stack memory?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31787950/5779732) explains what value types go to heap.

If this is the case, there is very little or even near to nothing that goes on stack memory.

**I suspect I am misunderstanding something.**

If almost all data goes to heap memory, I do not understand importance/role of stack memory.

Please explain.

---

Following two articles explains much about memory management in simple way.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/

Comment: The stack is primarily for local variables and keeping track of those variables within a call tree.

Comment: Read Eric Lippert's [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/).

Comment: A stack is useful because it pushes and pops. That's no small advantage. That's why there *is* a stack. It *happens* to also be useful in memory allocation scenarios sometimes -- and from there Eric Lippert's explanation comes in.

Comment: Also from Mr Lippert - [The Truth about Value Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/): "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't think of it as "stack" and "heap". Think of it as **short term memory** and **long term memory**.  Now it becomes very easy to know what goes on the stack and what goes on the heap.  **Is the lifetime of the variable longer than the activation of the current method**?  If yes, then it is not short-lived, and has to go on the heap. If it is, then it *can* go on the stack.

For example:

```
class C {
  void M() {
    string s = Whatever();
    Something(s);
  }
}
```

The local variable `s` can go on the short term pool because it does not last longer than the activation of the method.

Now, you might say wait a minute, string is a reference type, so surely it goes on the heap.  And no, it does not.  **The string goes on the heap, but the variable does not contain a string**.  String is a reference type so **the variable contains a reference**, and **a reference can go on the stack**. The thing it *refers to* is on the heap, but the *reference itself* is a value, and that can go on the stack.

So stop thinking that the type of anything determines where it is stored.  The type is irrelevant.  Variables of value type or reference type can go on the short term pool if they are short-lived, and must go on the long term pool if they are not.

Now what about

```
class C { 
  void M() {
    int i = Whatever();
    X(() => i)
  }
}
```

Now can i go on the stack?  No.  `X` could store a copy of the delegate passed in, and that delegate needs to know the value of `i`, so the variable needs to live longer than the activation of method `M`, so `i` goes on the long-term pool.  `i` is on the heap here.

Again, the fact that it is an int is completely irrelevant.  It's a variable, it lives a long time, so it goes on the heap.

What about fields of a class, or elements of an array?  Those are variables. They live as long as the class instance or array instance lives, and therefore their lifetimes are not predictable, and therefore they go on the long-term pool.

Why do we have a short term pool and a long term pool?  Because the garbage collector for the short term pool is *extremely* fast and cheap compared to the garbage collector for the long term pool.  Thus we want to have the option of generating variables on the short term pool when we can -- which is when their lifetimes are *short*.

Comment: "... The thing it refers to is on the heap..." - Why? Is it always guaranteed to be allocated in the heap? If I have a `Tuple<int, int>` (a reference type) why is it required to be allocated in the heap?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Because the thing referred to is *not known to have a short lifetime*.  Now, there are scenarios where we *can* know that a particular reference is created in a method, never escapes the method, and is therefore unused after the method returns. In those cases the CLR *could* generate a reference to something on the stack. Current implementations do not; it's cheaper and easier to just have one allocator and collector for reference types. But *in principle* there is no objection to short-lived instances of reference types.